# Mysql query throwing error

Tags: mysql

I am getting a :

You have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that correspondes to....

here is my query. I do MSSQL, I am new to mysql .. Please help

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TIMESHEET WHERE EMPLOYEEID = '1' AND PERIODENDINGDATE = '2011-01-30')
   UPDATE TIMESHEET SET STATUSCODE = 'P', PERIODENDINGDATE = '2011-01-30', DEPARTMENTCODE = 'IT'
                        MINUTESMON = '200', MINUTESTUE= '200', MINUTESWED='200', MINUTESTHU='200'
                        MINUTESFRI='200', MINUTESSAT='200', MINUTESSUN='200'
ELSE
   INSERT INTO TIMESHEET (EMPLOYEEID, STATUSCODE, PERIODENDINGDATE, DEPARTMENTCODE, MINUTESMON, MINUTESTUE,
                          MINUTESWED, MINUTEDTHU, MINUTESFRI, MINUTESSAT, MINUTESSUN)
          VALUES ('1','P','2011-01-30','IT','200','200','200','200','200','200','200')
```

Comment: i think you need  'on insert into .. on duplicate key update', http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: hmm no idea.. i dont know anything about mySql.. but know some about MSSQL

Comment: Ok, I dont know anything about mySql, but what happens if I insert a record then.. tomorrow.. i go back and try to insert another record.. but i dont want it to insert a new record because yesterday I entered it already...I just want to updated if thats the case.. now.. the only thing i know is the employeeid and the date.. but in that table there could be multiple records with the same employeeid but different dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is part of a stored procedure or function or trigger, this simply isn't a valid form for a MySQL query. You can't just write freeform logic into a single query with MySQL.

You probably want to write an [`INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query.

Comment: Ok, I dont know anything about mySql, but what happens if I insert a record then.. tomorrow.. i go back and try to insert another record.. but i dont want it to insert a new record because yesterday I entered it already...I just want to updated if thats the case.. now.. the only thing i know is the employeeid and the date.. but in that table there could be multiple records with the same employeeid but different dates?

Comment: Make (employeeid, date) the primary key of your table, then write an `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query. When you try to insert the second row with the same (employeeid, date) pair as the existing row, it will update that row instead of creating a new one. If for some reason you cannot create that primary key (office politics), then you will have to issue a `SELECT` query to see if the row exists then either send a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query as appropriate.

Comment: isnt that what I am doing in the query above.. I can not modify the tables... I am just struggling with the mySql syntax..based on what you are saying i am already doing that?

Comment: No. What you wrote is not a MySQL query, it's a program, and you can't do that. The `SELECT` part alone is a query. The `UPDATE` part alone is a query. The `INSERT` part alone is a query. You can send any one of those. From your application, the thing you're writing that talks to the database, you need to send the `SELECT` query alone. In your application, look at the result and decide whether you need to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Then send that query, alone. That means you will at minimum send two, separate, queries to the database from your application.

Comment: P.S. I'm sorry to hear you live in some kind of backwards world where you're expected to code against a database without a proper schema and aren't allowed to fix the schema.

Comment: ayayay... thats going to be painfull using what I am using...ok i will see what i can do.. thank you